# How to create TCP proxy for SSL stream

Tags: c#, ssl, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, tls1.2

There's a transparent BLE to IP communication established between mobile (Xamarin) and BLE device.
The high-level diagram is the following:

`Mobile TCP/IP socket <---> BLE Central <---> BLE Peripheral <---> SSL server on device`

I want to establish TLS session over BLE, for this purpose the client connects to Mobile TCP/IP server socket over SSLStream, but on a method AuthenticateAsClient it hangs and mobile TCP/IP socket doesn't receive any data.
Taking in account that SSL is located above TCP I was expecting that TCP socket will receive all data related to SSL handshake process..

Please advise any ideas how to solve this.

Comment: Is the "BLE Peripheral" actually providing a *transparent* pass-through network proxy?

Comment: @SushiHangover, yes. It is a transparent proxy, we tested with a proprietary communication protocol

Comment: @SushiHangover the main challenge is to establish connection between SSLStream from one side and TCPListener from the other side, assuming all SSL session related data will be passed through BLE proxy back and forth